# cannot install the features of ML in wso2cep

Tags: wso2-cep, wso2-ml

I want to use machine learning algorithms in wso2cep and i want to use wso2ML. I try to install machine learning features in wso2cep according to this link:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ML100/WSO2+CEP+Extension+for+ML+Predictions

But when i install features, i get this message:

> Installing the selected features, this may take a while to complete ...

And it has remained the same for hours without getting any error!!

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. I select version 1.0.2 of features and it install successfully.